# How to stop Thunar from being default file browser?

Tags: nautilus, default-programs, thunar

On a relatively new installation, Thunar has become the default file browser simply by using it.

While I can open Nautilus easily enough, I'd rather it remained as the default file browser(especially when I choose to view files in dual pane).

How can I change my default file manager?

Comment: you can set your preferred applications in the preferences sub-menu of the gnome menu.

Comment: No you can't. That is a seriously lame and half baked tool which only allows setting Web Browser, Mail Reader, Multimedia Player, Terminal Emulator and 2 Accessibility settings. Why one needs 4 tabs to do 6 things beats me as being design madness.

Comment: hmm, why don't you get rid of thunar?, other thing you can try is to use ubuntu tweak and chnage there the default file browser

Comment: See also: [How to use as default nautilus in XFCE?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66662/how-to-use-as-default-nautilus-in-xfce)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although convoluted, I believe this link will help you from help.ubuntu.com:

[Default File Manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DefaultFileManager)

Check for the secion titled “Changing Your Default File Manager”

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 19):

Another method to set nautilus as default using GUI :-

1. Click on the top-left Xubuntu logo, it will display a menu
2. Select *Settings* ➞ *Settings manager*

   [image: settings manager menu]
3. The *Settings* window will open, Click on the *Preferred Applications* icon.

   [image: settings manage window]
4. Then click on the *Utilities* tab and select nautilus from *File Manager* section

   [image: preferred application window]

That's it. Now nautilus becomes your default File manager.

Comment: But the desktop is still Thunar's.

Answer (score 5):

I have a simple solution.

Run this command: `exo-preferred-applications`

I am using Opensuse 11.4 + Gnome 2.32.1

Thunar became default file browser after playing with XFCE, now I back on Gnome. ;-)

*Edit: This method has been tested on Ubuntu by [Park Jun-Hong](https://askubuntu.com/users/73059/park-jun-hong) and found to work.*

Answer (score 3):

I assume this happens in the same way that [it can with Dolphin](http://www.ignition-project.com/articles/2009/01/08/fix-dolphin-hijacks-the-gnome-places-menu). The fix (at least for `10.10`) is to run a few gconf commands to get things back to normal. I suggest you run the following in a terminal:

```
gconftool-2 --set --type=string /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/file/command 'nautilus "%s"'
gconftool-2 --set --type=bool /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/file/enabled true
gconftool-2 --set --type=bool /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/file/need-terminal false
```

Comment: Nope! I restarted after running the commands but Thunar continues to muscle out Nautilus. Testing things just for a few minutes doesn't show any chages at all. I suppose that is both good and bad!

Answer (score 3):

Go to "Preferred Applications." I couldn't find this item on the GNOME menu but was able to find it via Gnome-Do just by writing in `preferred applications`. Once there go to Utilities tab and select Nautilus from there.

Hope this helps someone later on -- I realise this is an old question.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to stop that problem (because it's an issue that even solved can resurface anytime) is to get rid of Thunar if you use Gnome/Unity and not Xfce.

From my experience I can say that Nautilus and Thunar are not tuned up to be used one beside the other, both trying to take over each-other's business, changing the desktop and behaving like they were in their "normal" desktop environments (as if Thunar is asking for Xfce and Nautilus for Gnome/Unity). Their parallel use might make sense only for testing purposes. I think most combinations of file browsers are ok, but not that one.

Comment: I use Nautilus and Thunar side-by-side all the time, without problems. Sometimes Nautilus will try to take over the desktop, but this hasn't caused me any problems and it goes away when I make sure there are no `nautilus` processes running anymore.

Comment: This really isn't an answer. More of a very long comment and should be deleted or moved.

Comment: @KevinBowen - it's also old, just like the question. Are you still having this problem?

Comment: @KevinBowen strictly speaking, it is an answer. It is suggesting that the OP remove thunar altogether. That is, in fact, an answer to the question.