# Not able to set Nautilus as my default file manager

Tags: xubuntu, filemanager, preferences

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to stop Thunar being default file browser](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47208/how-to-stop-thunar-being-default-file-browser)

I wanted to try out xfce and installed it. When I launched the file manager in xfce, it prompted me to choose between thunar and nautilus and I chose Thunar just to try it out. But now, I moved back to gnome 3 and Thunar is still my default file manager. I want to get back to Nautilus as my default file manager and I am not able to do it. I tried the steps provided in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DefaultFileManager. But thats not working too.