# How to set Thunar as a default file manager?

Tags: nautilus, default, thunar

Is it possible to make Thunar my default file manager in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

I've installed Thunar and I must say there's really visible performance difference compared to gnome-shell default manager.

How can I make this my preferred file manager?

Comment: Similar question, but focused on changing from Thunar back to Nautilus: http://askubuntu.com/questions/47208/how-to-stop-thunar-being-default-file-browser?rq=1

Comment: Have a look at: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DefaultFileManager

Comment: in order to run "exo-preferred-applications" you must have installed "exo-utils" package (which is not by default in Saucy)

Comment: In my system Thunar appears as the default, but nautilus opens in some occasions. Nautilus sucks,  I had to removed it!

Answer (score 24):

- Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>).
- Run the following command:

  ```
  exo-preferred-applications
  ```
- Next, go to *Utilities > Default File Manager*, and choose the file manager that you want to use as your default.

  [image]

Comment: Worked like a charm in ``12.04``. Thanks

Comment: Doesn't work in 15.04. I have both Thunar and Nautilus installed.

Comment: This works in Ubuntu Gnome 16.04  as well.

Comment: This is not working in my 16.04. Nautilus gets invoked.

Answer (score 12):

The setting from Kevin Bowen's answer is not enough for all scenarios:

```
~$ xdg-mime query default inode/directory
nautilus-folder-handler.desktop
```

So applications using xdg (or another interface to `.desktop` files) to open directories will still use Nautilus. Run this¹ to change to Thunar:

```
xdg-mime default Thunar.desktop inode/directory
```

Note bene: using `gio mime` seems to be equivalent.

---

1. On some versions of Ubuntu, the file may be called `thunar.desktop`.

Comment: @Flimm I'm reverting your edit since I can't confirm `thunar.desktop` exists; it's definitely called `Thunar.desktop` on my 18.04  machine. I'll include a note to try the other spelling, though, and revisit for 20.04.

Comment: @Flimm On 20.04, both exists. Huh.

Comment: Yep, it's thunar.desktop on my Ubuntu 20.04.3

Answer (score 0):

By the way you need to open it just one time, after that it would be Default File Manager for you.

However, you can change the default file manager and also restore to previous one, check the link:
[Default File Manager Official Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DefaultFileManager)