# Open a thunar directory with an application action

Tags: xubuntu, directory, thunar

**Problem**

When opening a thunar directory from an application for example:

- from firefox in the downloads section you click on 'open with folder'
- or from thunderbird troubleshooting you click on 'open directory'

*... the action is mishandled with opening of the dirctory with an other application.*

---

**Solution**

Was able to resolve this problem as follow:

- open thunar with root privilege
- go to
- ´`/usr/share/applications/`´
- open the file '`defaults.list`'
- save the file as defaults.list.backup-original
- open again the file '`defaults.list`'
- go to 'inode/directory=' (press [ctrl]+[f], paste 'inode/directory=nautilus-folder-handler.desktop' and hit [enter])
- change '`inode/directory=nautilus-folder-handler.desktop`'
- change into '`inode/directory=`**thunar**`-folder-handler.desktop`'
- save the file and **check if it works**

---

**Furthermore**

Noticed that the file mimeinfo.cahce within the same directory has the line:

- 'inode/directory=org.gnome.baobab.desktop;Thunar-folder-handler.desktop;'

Did change this line because initially the program baobab was opening instead of the directory within the folder manager.

*But it had no effect.*

And after selecting a file and choose open 'send to (application)' the action to open a folder didn't open baobab any more but this application. It happend every time when opening a directory from various applications.

So in the end this line was left untouched.

---

*Perhaps somebody*

*with more knowledge about thunar*

*can explain thunar working*

*and can confirm if this solution is good enough.*

---

other threads with similar issue:

https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=4128

https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=3163

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1278845

Answer (score 0):

Actually the directory '`/usr/share/applications/`' does not contain the file to edit. The file mentioned is a link of ...

'`default.list`'

pointing to the located in:

'`/etc/gnome/`'

Although the method mentioned does edit the right file.

---

I think thunar and nautilus are written with capital in the command. So, it should be:

'*inode/directory=**N**autilus-folder-handler.desktop*'

or

'*inode/directory=**T**hunar-folder-handler.desktop*'

---

Maybe setting thunar as default manager could help, see:

[How to set Thunar as a default file manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253131/how-to-set-thunar-as-a-default-file-manager)

Maybe this command might help:

'`sudo gio mime inode/directory Thunar.desktop`'

---

Also it seems Baobab doesn play nice with file managers, see:

https://forum.manjaro.org/t/disk-usage-analyzer-baobab-r-click-open-folder-not-working/50890

---

*Further more, it seems by removing Baobab from the system gives the default behaviour back and resolves the problem.*

*But removing an(other) application is not the way to go.*

---