# How do I set Thunar as the default file manager in 23.10?

Tags: filemanager, 23.10, thunar

Before I start, I wanted to say that this is my first question in askubuntu.com. Anyway, I want to set Thunar file manager as my default one. I can open the app fine, but I have to do it manually. The final result that I want is that if I were to do "show in folder" the system would use Thunar instead of Nautalis. I did `xdg-mime query default inode/directory` and the result reads `thunar.desktop`. But when I do 'show in folder' anywhere in the system, it *still* opens nautalis. Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: you might find the answer in [this its FOSS post](https://itsfoss.com/change-default-applications-ubuntu/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set Thunar as a default file manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253131/how-to-set-thunar-as-a-default-file-manager)