# Nautilus on Xubuntu's desktop?

Tags: nautilus, xubuntu, thunar

I like Nautilus better than Thunar, so I use Nautilus on Xubuntu, but Thunar is still on the desktop. Can I switch that somehow?

Comment: Have a look at http://askubuntu.com/a/172673/186134

Comment: Nope, I mean on the desktop, when all programs are closed or minimised. Not the default file browser, I've already set that to Nautilus.

Comment: So the desktop uses nautilus? As it's icons etc?

Comment: [That](http://askubuntu.com/questions/47208/how-to-stop-thunar-being-default-file-browser) *should* change it for the desktop as well.

Answer (score 0):

Replace Thunar with Nautilus in Xubuntu session configuration:

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-session.xml
```

From:

```
  <property name="Client3_Command" type="array">
    <value type="string" value="Thunar"/>
    <value type="string" value="--daemon"/>
  </property>
```

To:

```
  <property name="Client3_Command" type="array">
    <value type="string" value="nautilus"/>
    <value type="string" value="--no-default-window"/>
  </property>
```